# Error while uploading a file to S3: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to a S3 Bucket using the following shell script:

```
file=somefile.txt
bucket=some-bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

The script above successfully uploads the file to the bucket. However, it doesn't make the file/object public so when I try to download the file using `wget https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/somefile.txt` it fails.

To make the object/file public I tried to pass the `acl="x-amz-acl:public-read"` access control to it while uploading (script below):

```
file=somefile.txt
bucket=some-bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
acl="x-amz-acl:public-read"
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n$acl\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "$acl" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

But, when I execute this script it fails to upload the file to S3 and throws the following error:

```
< ..Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</ Code>
<..Message >The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</ Message>
```

What could be the issue? Is there something wrong with way I am trying to provide the access control in the script?

Comment: Side-comment: If you are going to upload via shell, have you considered using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead?

Comment: I know I can use AWS CLI and I have used it to do the same task. But, now I can't use it because the Jenkins server in which I have to run this script doesn't have AWS-CLI installed and I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: Might be helpful? [Pre-signed URLs and x-amz-acl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953686/174777)

Comment: The script worked when I made my S3 bucket public. However, for a private Bucket the script isn't working even though I am using my secret key and access key to upload it. For, private bucket if I use `authenticated-read` it works. While downloading it using `wget` I gotta provide credentials.

Comment: The change to the script looks correct.  Does the error message not include a `<StringToSign>` element?

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot, yes it does.

Comment: @ANIL that's giving you exactly what the service **expects** you to have used in your `stringToSign` based on the request it received -- it is not giving you what you actually used, so you will want to compare it carefully against what you are generating.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you really should have quotes around the variable in `echo -en "${stringToSign}"`